# C++ non-virtual class member variables memory layout?

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, memory-layout

I have a non-virtual class template `A` as below and I do the following

```
#include <iostream>
// my class template
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
    // bunch of other non-virtual member functions including constructors, etc
    // and obviously no user-defined destructor
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    //now I do the following
    A<double> a;
    a.x = 1.0; // not important this
    a.y = 2.0;
    a.z = 3.0;

    // now the concerned thing 
    double* ap = (double*)&a;
    double* xp = &(a.x);

    // can I correctly and meaningfully do the following?     
    double new_az = ap[2]; // guaranteed to be same as a.z (for any z) ? ** look here **
    double new_z = xp[2]; // guaranteed to be same as a.z (for any z) ? ** look here **

    std::cout<<new_az<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<new_z<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, is it guaranteed that if I use a raw point to object `A` or to the member variable `a.x`, I will correctly get the other variables?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, instead of just using `std::array`?

Comment: @CodyGray Although my demonstration class here is simple. My actual class is more complex. And I have to pass its member variables to a  function from a library (which is not mine and uses pointer interface for some obvious reasons). That's why these two options  immediately came in my mind.

Comment: There is no such guarantee. The standard says that `x`, `y`, and `z`, will have [increasing addresses](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) but does not preclude a private or protected member from being inserted between them.

Comment: Compiler is also allowed to add padding between members for the sake of memory access patterns optimization. For example, if you create a `struct A { char x; int y }` most probably there will be a few unused bytes between `x` and `y`, just because it's faster to access `int` when it's aligned.

Comment: @yeputons What if the case is just x, y, z of type T? And what happens when linking functions with such classes in the function argument?

Comment: It's still allowed to insert padding. Consider the case where `T` is type `short`. If `short` is distinct from `int` on your target system, and there is an access penalty for unaligned data, many compilers will pad out `short` members. As to your response to me, why does the library require *member variables*? Why can't you just pass the address of a variable of the appropriate type? How can it tell whether they're members?

Comment: @user62039 I'd recommend just using an array instead of three consecutive members - something is definitely guaranteed for arrays.

Comment: Use an array (preferably `std::array`), there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

As many users pointed out, there is no guarantee that the memory layout of your structure will be identical to the appropriate array. And "ideologically correct" way to access members by index would be creating some ugly `operator []` with a `switch` inside it.

However, speaking practically, there is usually no problem with your approach, and the suggested solutions are inferior in terms of code generated and run-time performance.

I can suggest 2 other solutions.

1. Keep your solution, but verify in **compile-time** that your structure layout corresponds to an array. In your specific case putting `STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(a) == sizeof(double)*3);`
2. Change your template class to be actually an array, and convert the `x,y,z`variables into the access functions into the elements of the array.

I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
// my class template
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T m_Array[3];

    T& x() { return m_Array[0]; }
    const T& x() const { return m_Array[0]; }

    // repeat for y,z
    // ...
};
```

If you make the length of the array (i.e. dimension of the represented vector) a template parameter as well, you may put a 'STATIC_ASSERT' in each access function to ensure the actual existence of the member.

Comment: I thank everyone for the useful information and suggestive alternatives. And as suggested by most of you, I have modified my class templates to use a simple array as in this answer by valdo. This is the most efficient and correct way to do what I required.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee, not the way you do it.  If T is a int8_t, for example, it would work *only* if you specified 1-byte packing.

The easiest, and correct way to do this, would be to add an operator [] to your template class, something like:

```
T& operator[](size_t i)
{
  switch(i)
  {
  case 0: return x;
  case 1: return y;
  case 2: return z:
  }
  throw std::out_of_range(__FUNCTION__);
}

const T& operator[](size_t i) const
{
  return (*const_cast<A*>(this))[i];  // not everyone likes to do this.
}
```

But this is not really efficient. A more efficient way is to have your vector (or point) coordinates in a array, and x(), y(), z() member functions to access them.  Then you example would work in all cases, provided you implement a T* operator in your class.

```
operator T*() { return &values[0]; }
operator const T*()const  { return &values[0]; }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do such things:

```
template <typename T>
class FieldIteratable
{
  using Data = std::array<T, 5/*magic number*/>;
  Data data_;
  public:
  const Data & data() { return data_; }
  T& a1 = data_[0]; // or some macro
  char padding1[3]; // you can choose what field is iteratable
  T& a2 = data_[1];
  char padding2[3]; // class can contain other fields can be
  T& a3 = data_[2];
  char padding3[3];
  T& a4 = data_[3];
  char padding4[3];
  T& a5 = data_[4];


};



int main() {

  FieldIteratable<int> fi;

  int* a = &fi.a1;
  *a++ = 0;
  *a++ = 1;
  *a++ = 2;
  *a++ = 3;
  *a++ = 4;

  std::cout << fi.a1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << fi.a2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << fi.a3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << fi.a4 << std::endl;
  std::cout << fi.a5 << std::endl;

  for(auto i :fi.data())
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it makes the type non-copyable and non-movable. Also the memory footprint of this.

Comment: Why in the world are you manually inserting padding? Just to prove it works even with it there?

Comment: @aschepler yes.

Comment: @Sopel type can be copied and moved. Just do it with **data_**. As for memory - it will probably be handled by optimisation

Comment: well yes, Data can be copied, but FieldIterable not. And I doubt it can be optimized.

Comment: I meant assignable, sorry